# What is "Geschwisterkind von muetterlicher seit"?

Tags: 18th-century, france, relationship-analysis

I have a death record from 1790 Alsace. It concerns a one-year old child named Johann Philipp Gassmann, son of Johann Erhardt Gassmann and Margaretha Bley. As seems customary in Alsace at the time, the entry in the church register was signed by several witnesses (for lack of a better term), including Daniel Bley, the "unmarried brother of the child's mother", and Michael Heinrich (not sure if that's the last name), who is identified as "Geschwisterkind von muetterlicher seit".

What is that?

How does he fit into the family?

Can it be inferred that Heinrich is his last name?

Could it be Bley?

---

Someone wanted to see an image of the record. This was actually a bit trickier than I thought, but here it is:[image]

My read of this record: "Den 10ten May starb an einem ??fluss und damit verbundenen Gichtern des Johann Erhard Gassmann Buergers zu Birlenbach mit Margaretha einer gebohrenen Bleyin seiner Ehefrau ehelich erzeugtes Soehnlein Namens Johann Philipp. Es ward den 12ten darauf auf dem dasigen Gottesacker zur Erde bestattet, alt 1 Jahr weniger 9 Tage.

Bezeugen:  Erhard Gassmann als Vatter;
Michael Heinrich, Geschwisterkind von muetterlicher Seit, von Birlenbach;
Daniel Bley von Birlenbach der ledige des verstorbenen Kindes Mutter Bruder;
G S Lauffer, Pfarrer"

My translation: "On May 10th died of ??? Johann Philipp, the infant son of Johann Erhardt Gassmann, citizen of Birlenbach, and his wife Margaretha, nee Bley. He was buried on the 12th in the churchyard there, aged 1 year minus 9 days.

Witnesses: Erhard Gassmann, the father; 
Michael Heinrich, ??? relative on the mother's side;
Daniel Bley, unmarried brother of the dead child's mother; 
G S Lauffer, priest."

Comment: I believe that Heinrich is child of sister of mother of that person. Or something similar

Comment: Geschwister = sibling(s). But would like to see the whole text, as it is not clear from the phrase alone, whose sibling is Michael Heinrich's parent might be.

Comment: Are you working from someone else's transcription, or an image of the document? Also -- gentle reminder that comments are for improving the questions, not answering them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources which could be used in solving this problem include:

FamilySearch Wiki: [German Genealogical Word List](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/German_Genealogical_Word_List#M)

Google Translate: https://translate.google.com/

Google Translate parses *Geschwisterkind* as the child of a sibling (so in this case, nephew).

(Compare *Geschwister* = siblings, brothers and sisters from the Genealogical Word List)

For *muetterlicher*, Google Translate suggested *mütterlich* = maternal

Comparing the entry to other entries can sometimes help.

In cases like this, it's easier for the community to determine what might be said when we can see a snippet of an image.

Comment: That far I got, but "child of a sibling" is an odd turn of phrase. I presume Michael Heinrich would be the deceased child's cousin on the mother's side. Since he is signing his name in the church register, I assume he must be at least 16-18 years old, and is possibly a second cousin.